# MySQL select unique row entries of a column as columns in a new view or table

Tags: mysql, select, join, union

I have a dilemma. I am using a CMS that creates a database table where the records are populated as follows:

```
+------------+----------------+
| field_name |  field_value   |
+------------+----------------+
| your-name  | Adam           |
| your-email | adam@email.com |
| your-name  | Ben            |
| your-email | en@email.com   |
+------------+----------------+
```

where field_name and field_value are column names. Also, 'your-name' and 'your-email' are are the input names of forms in a webpage.

(there are other columns but none of them have a unique row entry)

My question is, how do i create a table or view so that I can get to this from the above table?

```
+-----------+----------------+
| your-name |   your-email   |
+-----------+----------------+
| Adam      | Adam@email.com |
| Ben       | Ben@email.com  |
+-----------+----------------+
```

I have thought about creating views and joining them but I cannot seem to get it working.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: sorry, have to add this: there is no unique id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an ID in your table? If you have, you could use this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN field_name='your-name' THEN field_value END) your_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN field_name='your-email' THEN field_value END) your_email
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cef4d/1).

Comment: @echo_me without an ID it is not possible to answer, but i guess there has to be an ID

Comment: yeah, that's the thing this table has no id. it's weird. but without disclosing its a popular plugin for a popular CMS.

Comment: @NepzeTyson it's weird if there's no id... but is there something you can use to order your rows? if rows can be ordered using an ORDER BY there might be an alternative solution, otherwise i don't think it's possible

Comment: well if focused on just my objective, part of which would be to filter out the form inputs coming from the same IP address, i could maybe accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your table 1 have kind of an id column like this (so that (id, field_name) is the primary key of this table)?

```
+----+------------+----------------+
| id | field_name |  field_value   |
+----+------------+----------------+
| 1  | your-name  | Adam           |
| 1  | your-email | adam@email.com |
| 2  | your-name  | Ben            |
| 2  | your-email | en@email.com   |
+----+------------+----------------+
```

Then you could do...

```
SELECT DISTINCT myTableAlias.id,
    (SELECT field_value FROM table
     WHERE id=myTableAlias.id AND field_name = 'your-name') your-name,
    (SELECT field_value FROM table
     WHERE id=myTableAlias.id AND field_name = 'your-email') your-email,
FROM table myTableAlias
```

Comment: no unfortunately it's a poorly designed database in that regard. it has no unique id.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no `id` field or something similar? Having in mind that relational database systems do not make any guarantee about row ordering, how can you conclude at all that the E-Mail address `adam@email.com` belongs to user `Adam`!?

Comment: See that's the weird thing. It has none. I'll double check again tonight if there's something similar to an id.

Now, by id, you mean something that increments correct?

Comment: By id, I mean something that correlates `your-name` rows to `your-email` rows. Or I could say: By id I mean a column so that (id, field_name) is a unique key. See my table above.